# Can offers to international students be rescinded if grades received following the application slightly lower their GPA?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am an international student who has been accepted into mathematics department at UCLA.

In my application for the last semester I gave my grade point average as 9.5/10. I was taking two courses and was hoping that I would get a 10 and a 9, making the average 9.5.

But unfortunately the grades in both the courses slipped up to a 9 and a 8 , making the average 8.5/10.

I haven't informed them of this, and I was hoping that it wouldn't matter. I am going to get my visa next week, and I am really paranoid that my admission may get rescinded.

What do you guys think ?

Comment: It's not clear to me (not being familiar with the US system) what level your acceptance is at. Undergraduate or postgrad? If it's undergrad, I'm afraid that makes it off-topic on this site.

Comment: You should probably inform them. The longer you wait, the worse the consequences are going to be. IMO, the offer is unlikely to be rescinded, but if it is and they find out it later, it will reflect very badly on you. Also, are you prepared to spend 5 years being paranoid that someone somehow finds out your grade?

Comment: @OlgaK this is wrong advice.  You only need to send in the grades you get after you apply if your offer letter (or other relevant document) explicitly says it is required.

Comment: I'm a little confused - shouldn't your GPA involve more than just your final semester of courses? If you got a 1 pt lower grade on just those two courses, that wouldn't have nearly as big of an influence on your overall GPA.

Comment: @OlgaK I think the idea that you would need to be paranoid about this after starting the program is ridiculous. Who would care?  Once the OP is established in the program, no one will give the least thought to his/her undergraduate grades.

Comment: @BenWebster I didn't say OP would "need" to be paranoid. I doubt polling on stack exchange will relieve his current paranoia completely. Only the school can do that.

Comment: @OlgaK You said "The longer you wait, the worse the consequences are going to be."  If that's not arguing for the need to be paranoid, what is?  This is totally wrong; one the OP starts the program, no one will care in the least was his/her undergraduate grades were for better or worse.

Comment: @BenWebster you are right, I should have phrased it differently.

Answer (score 7):

As someone with some experience on the other end of math graduate admissions, let me preface this by saying I really doubt that anyone cares; a program like UCLA looks at a lot more than grades (especially for foreign students).  At this point it would be really disruptive for them to drop a student from the program (it's not like there are other students of the same caliber waiting around to be admitted), so they are not looking for reasons to do so.  This is probably hard to imagine after many years of people telling your grades are the most important thing, but for math grad school, they are really actually not.  They are a proxy for the ability to do good research in math, and the people running the program know they are a bad proxy and take them with a grain of salt.

So, the important thing to do here is calm down.  Imagine this from the perspective of the department; all the people making these decisions have a lot of other things to worry about, you are one of many grad students they admitted this year, and these grades are a very small part of why. Your grades are not something they want to expend energy paying attention to.   Even if your offer is conditional, I think this condition would only be used in really dramatic cases; I've never heard of this happening.

Look carefully at your offer letter.  Either it will say the offer is contingent on your grades this semester, or it won't.  (Incidentally, this info should have been in your post; answering questions well on this site is hard enough without people withholding obviously important information).  If it doesn't, and they haven't asked about your grades, then drop the subject from your mind and never speak of it again.  If it does, I would probably still not do anything unless they ask.  If they really want that information they'll ask for it.  If they ask, just write back saying "I got an 8/10 in X and 9/10 in Y.  Looking forward to meeting you in August." Don't try to explain why your grades are not what you expected. Just act as if everything is normal, and I'm sure things will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The offer (which you have accepted) itself cannot be reasonably rescinded. However, the offer should clearly spell out whether it was conditional (to you obtaining certain minimum marks) or not. If it was conditional, then obviously failing to obtain the marks required (which may be lower than what you told them) implies that you have not secured a place.

If the offer contained a vague condition (such as *obtaining good marks*), then you should inform them about your actual marks as soon as possible and ask for clarification.

One problem with international students is that the marks cannot be easily compared to those of home students or students from other countries, simply because the teaching and grading systems vary.

Having said all that, 8.5/10 is still a very good mark (in most grading systems) and you should not worry too much at this moment, but don't delay clarifying your position.

Comment: I am not sure this really answers the question.  My impression is that it's common for US grad school admissions to be conditional on maintaining good grades, without explicitly stating a required minimum; it would be reviewed on a case-by-case basis.  So reading the offer won't resolve the OP's question.  Personally I don't think OP's situation would be likely to lead to rescission, but I am not the one making the decision.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, the offer should state the condition, even if vague. The answer is still correct: the offer as such cannot be rescinded, but may have a, possibly vague, condition.